# Saving complex object to IsolatedStorage as XML file in Windows Phone (C#)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am using this code as my IsolatedStorage Helper.

```
public class IsolatedStorageHelper
{
    public const string MyObjectFile = "History.xml";
    public static void WriteToXml<T>(T data, string path)
    {
        // Write to the Isolated Storage
        var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
        try
        {
            using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, data); //This line generates the exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace));
            //MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    public static T ReadFromXml<T>(string path)
    {
        T data = default(T);
        try
        {
            using (var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using (var stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(path, FileMode.CreateNew))
                {
                    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                    data = (T)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
            //add some code here
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am saving an object of my class PdfFile, which has ImageSource as one of its properties.
But an exception is generated while saving the object and it states `System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.`
I would like to know what this means, and how I would solve this. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to serialize a class that contains a variable / property of type `BitmapImage`. You can't serialize that type, so you get the mentioned exception. Try to work around by serializing a name or something like this and instantiating the BitmapImage on deserialization from that information.

Comment: can BitmapImage be stored as IsolatedStorageSetting?

Comment: You can try. To cite http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266(v=pandp.11).aspx: "and for non-serializable objects"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save something in iso storage which is not serializable then you can still do so if you write your own serialize method.

Presumably the BitmapImage is not an original part of your app or you would already have the file for it, so I guess it must be a newly acquired bitmap.

Convert your BitmapImage to an array of bytes and you should have no problem.